# Ionic 4 Angular App works on ionic s but when building for browser white screen of death

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

So I'm attempting to build an Angular/Ionic 4 app for the browser. Everything looks great when serving and viewing with "ionic serve" but as soon as the app is built using:

```
ionic cordova build browser --prod --release --debug
```

The dreaded white screen of death appears. No console errors other than:

```
Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.
19.d726578d250ff131c3b2.js:1 test
cordova.be00a3c9f5babbb22844.js:1 adding proxy for Device
19.d726578d250ff131c3b2.js:1 t {__zone_symbol__state: null, 
__zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}__zone_symbol__state: 
true__zone_symbol__value: []__proto__: Object
19.d726578d250ff131c3b2.js:1 []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
```

I've been drilling my brains for over 24 bloody hours on this one. If anyone has any ideas it would be massively appreciated.

Many thanks and best regards,

Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm

Do you want to build a **PWA** using Ionic and Angular?

Or a **Hybrid Mobile App** using Ionic and Angular and Cordova (PhoneGap).

Comment: I think your comment has just made me realise I'm looking at this wrong. I should be using the pwa toolkit that ionic provides to build the version for the web. Thanks Robinyo!!!!

Comment: Actually, you have two options if you want to build a PWA using Ionic.

You can take the @ionic/angular approach or you can choose to use Ionic's PWA toolkit.

I prefer the first option which leverages Angular's PWA tooling.

Comment: Some useful Ionic PWA links:

- [Optimising the performance of an Ionic PWA - Part 1](https://robferguson.org/blog/2018/04/16/0ptimising-the-performance-of-an-ionic-pwa-part-1/)
- [Optimising the performance of an Ionic PWA - Part 2](https://robferguson.org/blog/2018/04/17/optimising-the-performance-of-an-ionic-pwa-part-2/)
- [PWA Tips and Tricks](https://robferguson.org/blog/2018/09/14/pwa-tips-and-tricks/)

Comment: Actually might be better sticking with the current implementation if I can figure out why the white screen of death is causing me hell. I've stripped out all the cordova plugins and still no luck.